# Cannot access `id` field of OpenStruct instance

Tags: ruby

I have some code in Ruby like below:
Ruby version: 1.8.7

```
hash = OpenStruct.new(:id=>123, :name=>'wenbo')
puts "#{hash.id} -- #{hash.name}"

D:/workspace/wmch/rubytest/lib/variable.rb:17: warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id
27556896 -- wenbo
```

Can someone help me on how to get the id field value for 123?

Comment: I do not get this warning even with `ruby -w` under 1.9.2; what flavor and version of Ruby are you running?

Comment: @Phrogz 1.8.7, added the version infor to the question, thank you for your reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug/limitation of OpenStruct under 1.8.7 where there isn't a BlankSlate object, caused by an implementation that uses `method_missing` to decide if it's a special property or not.

Here's a custom class similar to OpenStruct that does what you ask for under 1.8.7; feel free to expand upon it and make it more feature rich.

```
class MemoStruct
  def initialize( h=nil )
    h.each{ |k,v| add_field(k,v) } if h
  end
  def add_field( name, value=nil )
    inst = :"@#{name}"
    (class << self; self; end).class_eval do
      define_method(name){ instance_variable_get inst }
      define_method("#{name}="){ |v| instance_variable_set inst,v }
    end
    instance_variable_set(inst,value)
  end
  def []=( name, value )
    add_field(name,value)
  end
end

hash = MemoStruct.new :id=>123, :name=>"Jim"
p hash.id
#=> 123

hash["new_field"] = "stuff"
p hash.new_field
#=> stuff
```

Comment: You're welcome; note that a major difference in the code I've supplied versus OpenStruct is that you cannot ask for a field that you have not yourself set; you can add that functionality via `method_missing` if you like. Since this class defines methods, I would recommend instead using `respond_to?` to decide if an instance does or does not have a certain property instead, however. Or, alternatively, `p hash.catz if hash.instance_variables.include?( :@catz )`

Comment: Cool solution. A nice addition is to be able to define chained associations of structs recursively.

Then with
`nested_struct = MemoStruct.new({:a => {:b => {:c => "nested value"}}})`
you can get the "nested value" with `nested_struct.a.b.c`

Here's a gist of a refactored version of Phrogz's nice code that includes recursion: https://gist.github.com/1421555

Answer (score 4):

This question is answered in this [blog post](http://www.fngtps.com/2007/using-openstruct-as-mock-for-activerecord/) with this simple line of code

```
OpenStruct.__send__(:define_method, :id) { @table[:id] }
```

Now you can set :id on an OpenStruct and not have it ignore you and call :object_id with a warning